# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbi

This query return below error.  Any one has any idea ???

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = (:id) ")
Employee getByid(@Bind("id") Integer id);
```

result:

```
2018-08-29 11:12:19.532 ERROR 9736 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: Could not clean up 
[statement:"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = (:id) ", located:"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = (:id) ", 
rewritten:"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = (?) ", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{id:1}, finder:[]}]] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1
```

Comment: Nope. that is NOT the JPA API. Kindly remove the `jpa` tag from the question

Comment: Is the stacktrace complete?
So, idk if `Employee` is mapped, but you can try expanding select columns list and map columns to bean via `@RegisterMapper(EmployeeMapper.class)`.

Comment: this one already added.  [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: Could not clean up [statement:"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = :id ", located:"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = :id ", rewritten:"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = ? ", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{id:1}, finder:[]}]] with root cause

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1

Comment: at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_171]

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have problem in your syntax. You are surrounding your parameter with brackets ().

Try this:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = :id ")
```

Comment: Still receiving the error.Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: Could not clean up 
[statement:"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = :id ", located:"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = :id ",
 rewritten:"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = ? ", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{id:1}, finder:[]}]] with root cause